# How do I create a method in a class to delete the class instance?

Tags: c#, class, methods

I have created an employee class, and after creating an object of the employee class you can set it with details such as: age and date of birth. A validate method in the class checks if the age conforms with the date of birth, if not the employee instance is to be deleted.

I created a class method that prints on screen that the instance is deleted, but I actually want the method to delete the instance for real.

Comment: What do you mean by "delete"?

Comment: I want to remove the class instance that does not pass validation

Answer (score 4):

You cannot delete an instance in c#, you can only remove any active references to it and let the GC do its job.

What you can do is split construction and validation into separate steps using the [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern). It might look something like this:

```
public class EmployeeBuilder
{
    private int age;
    public void SetAge(int age) => this.age = age;

    public Employee? ValidateAndCreate()
    {
        if (age < 20) return null;
        return new Employee(age);
    }
}

public class Employee
{
    public int Age {get;}
    public Employee(int age) => Age = age;
}
```

You might also want to take a look at the [Fluent builder pattern](https://medium.com/xebia-engineering/fluent-builder-pattern-with-a-real-world-example-7b61be375a40) for a variation of the same idea.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your need, you can use a soft delete pattern.
Add a IsDelete properties on your object.

But as already said by JonasH, it's better to not build an object if it's not valid!